# $\frac{\operatorname{Log}w}{w-1}$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to show that $g(w)=\frac{\operatorname{Log}w}{w-1}$ when $w \neq 1$ and $g(1)=1$ is analytic when $0<|w|<\infty$ and $- \pi < Arg (w) < \pi$.

I started out by finding the series for $\operatorname{Log} w$ by integrating both sides of $$\frac{1}{z}=\sum_{0}^\infty (-1)^n(z-1)^n$$ on a contour contained within $|z-1|<1$ connecting $1$ to $w$, now I have $\dfrac{\operatorname{Log}  w}{w-1} =\sum_{1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(w-1)^{n-1}$ for $|w-1|<1$

Where $ \operatorname{Log} $ is the principal logaritm.

Comment: "Principal", not "Principle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it all together: Domain of the numerator, domain of the denominator, anylysis of the point where things could go wrong. Now write it all up!

Hint: $1$ is a removable singularity of $g$.

Comment: What I have so far is that I should only worry about 1, because besides that point the function is analytic right?